# Concurrent send/receive go channel

Tags: concurrency, go, channel

I have a go channel called `queue` with let's say 100 as the buffer size. Many go routines can send data to this channel, and another go routine is sitting there to receive data from this channel. This is a long lasting process, meaning the channel is acting like a pipeline absorbing data from many ends and sinking data to one end. I do something like this in the receiving go routine:

```
for {
    for data := range queue {
        sink(data)
    }
}
```

Now my question is: what if some new data were sent to the channel buffer before the range loop is finished. Will the new data be available for the next range loop? Or they will be missed if concurrency is not taken into consideration in this case?

Comment: On your question from the [spec on chan type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types): A single channel may be used in send statements, receive operations, and calls to the built-in functions cap and len by any number of goroutines without further synchronization. So nothing will be lost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need one `for` loop. From the [spec on range expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements):

> For channels, the iteration values produced are the successive values sent on the channel until the channel is closed. If the channel is `nil`, the range expression blocks forever.

In this case, the range loop is not acting like a regular range over, for example, a slice. Instead, when an item can be read from the channel, the loop body processes it. Therefore, your nested loops should be replaced with the following:

```
for data := range queue {
    sink(data)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As [@Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29719829/89391) said, you only need a single `for`, since `range` will emit values from the channel, until it is closed.

Overall, the pattern you describe is called [fan-in](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines). A example for a basic producer/consumer setup can be found here: http://play.golang.org/p/AhQ012Qpwj. The range loop runs in the consumer:

```
// consumer acts as fan in, signals when it is done.
func consumer(out chan string, done chan bool) {
    for value := range out {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
    done <- true
}
```

Comment: A fan-in process is also known as a multiplexer because the messages have to be multiplexed, i.e. interleaved into a sequential order. Because the arrival of messages into the channel is concurrent, the order they are interleaved is arbitrary and approximates first-come-first-served.

Comment: Thanks. This is really the advantage of `Golang` which is awkward, or at least error prone to implement in other languages.